# Possible misuse of the comma operator here

Tags: c++

This is my specific case where I receive the warning: "possible misuse of comma operator here":

```
i++, j++;
```

but is this a misuse?

Comment: Why do you want to use the comma operator at all? Why not just use 2 lines of code and be clear of your intent. In all my close to 30 years of C++ coding did I ever need the comma operator.

Comment: warning from who? the compiler or your IDE/clang-tidy? I dont see any https://godbolt.org/z/h6xoWaKa6

Comment: IDE (Xcode) @HenriqueBucher

Comment: @HenriqueBucher XCode keeps an eye out for these things, as they can be mistakes.

Comment: There's no reason for it. It's a misuse. `;` is right there.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Perhaps in a `for` cycle for(i=0, j=0; i<n; i++, j++) ?

Comment: @tadman as far as I can remember XCode uses clang, no? But clang does not warn even with `-Wall -Wextra`. This is clang-tidy on the background but clang-tidy is notoriously pedantic.

Comment: You can fix the code easily enough:  `((void)i++), j++;`.  That should make the warning shut-up.

Comment: Soooooo, given @ripi's comment, can we have a bit more context please.  Also, is it your own code or does it come from somewhere else?

Comment: @HenriqueBucher As far as I know, XCode uses clang but with additional checks to be even more particular. Not sure if these map to command-line options, or if there's some other mechanism here. I think it relates to XCode's auto-correct capability, so it could be IDE-specific, not even a part of the compiler.

Comment: FWIW (and I agree with others' comments about this being misuse/abuse of the comma operator), clang-cl (in Visual Studio 2022) also gives this warning. It also (as Eljay) suggests casting the expression to `void` to silence the warning: *note: cast expression to void to silence warning* ...

Comment: @Ripi2 Sure, that's about the only place. But the way OP mentioned it iit looked like freestanding code.

Comment: It is my own code, freestanding, and I did not see any issues. What exactly is the issue? It is a single statement, with two variables being incremented, and the value of neither is being used, so it does not matter that the first's return is being thrown away.

Comment: By "possible misuse" I believe they are implying to a possible *wrong* use, which is not the case. This is a false positive. Static analysis tools give false positives all the time.

Comment: _What exactly is the issue?_ Bad practise?  I would say so, and there's no need to do it so why do it?

Comment: What does anyone think is the mistake in code like this?  Is anyone writing `if(foo) i++, j++;` (with, I suppose, bad whitespace) and hoping the increment of `j` is unconditional?

Comment: What do you mean by unconditional @DavisHerring ? The advantage there seems to be the avoidance of braces.

Comment: @user129393192: I mean that in that circumstance, it makes a difference whether you use `;` or `,`, and you could theoretically want one but use the other (which affects which actions are controlled by the conditional).  Usually, they mean the same thing or you just can’t use `;` anyway.

Comment: How does it make a difference @DavisHerring

Comment: If I’m understanding, it’s a single statement, and like I said, it affects the braces … so you don’t need braces because they are both under the conditional.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by Davis Herring's (initial) comment but posted as an answer because formatting:

```
...
if (foo)
    i++,
j++;
...
```

See it now, OP?

Comment: They are both under the conditional, correct?

Comment: @user129393192: That’s the point: if it were a `;`, they wouldn’t both be, and we’re imagining someone who thought they were (per the indentation).  Not that I think this is a good justification for having the warning.

Comment: I see. My reasoning was actually to avoid braces in the first place, like I mentioned earlier @DavisHerring

Comment: @user129393192 My advice is to bite the bullet and include the braces.  'Shortcuts' like this have a tendency to come back and bite you.

Comment: @DavisHerring My thinking there, with that code and indentation, is that this might be a simple typo, and therefore a rather insidious bug.  On that basis, I _like_ the warning.  Good example you dreamed up, btw.